# How to remove Open CTI VF softphone page from salesforce left side

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, opencti

[image]

Open CTI Softphone VF page is showing in salesforce left side. How to remove this ? Screenshot attached

Answer (score 3):

Call center users will always see the softphone in the Salesforce Classic UI. The only way to stop displaying the softphone on those pages is to remove the user from the call center.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cti_admin_manageagentsremove.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I want it to display in salesforce service console but not in left side of salesforce as it shown in the screenshot

Comment: If you're a call center user, you'll always see the softphone outside of the console on the left side of the page. There isn't a way to hide that, apart from removing the user from the call center.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Exactly i need to remove softphone from left side not from console. if i remove the user from call center then not able to see softphone in console also.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Softphone appears in the left column in the 'non-console' view and as a console component when you're in the console. You can't remove it from just one place.